# Python RE match not open bracket then string

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the following pattern using python's `re.search`:

((not open bracket, then 1-3 spaces) or (the start of the string)) then (characters 1 or E) then (any number of spaces) then (close bracket).

Here is what I have so far:

```
re.search(r'((^\(\s{1,3})|^)[1tE]\s+\)', text)
```

want to match examples

```
text = "  E  )"
text = "1 )"
```

Dont want to match example

```
text = "( 1 )
```

Comment: You say "not open bracket" but use `\(` that matches it, why? Try `re.search(r'^(?:[^(]\s{1,3})?[1tE]\s+\)', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Xryk5/1).

Comment: Should this also match? `%  E  )`

Comment: Hi, did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following patterns:

- `(`

  - `( not open bracket, then 1-3 spaces)` - `[^(]\s{1,3}`
  - `or` - `|`
  - `(the start of the string)` - `^`
- `)`
- `(characters 1 or E)` - `[1E]`
- `(any number of spaces)` - `\s*`
- `(close bracket)` - `\)`.

Joining all of those into one pattern:

```js
(?:[^(]\s{1,3}|^)[1E]\s*\)
```

To match the entire string, add anchors, `^` and `$`:

```js
^(?:[^(]\s{1,3}|^)[1E]\s*\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Xryk5/2).

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, use a capturing one if you need to access its value in the future.

You can use a verbose regex notation to make it more readable and maintainable:

```py
re.search(
    r"""
    (?:
        [^(]\s{1,3}  # not open bracket, then 1-3 spaces
        |            # or
        ^            # the start of the string
    )
    [1E]  # characters 1 or E
    \s*   # any number of spaces
    \)    # close bracket
    """,
    text,
    re.VERBOSE
)
```